# $\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x)^{\cot x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

The following question is from cengage calculus . Illustration 2.95 but the explanation isn't clear to me

$\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x)^{\cot x}$

It is to be solved by using the identity : $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = e$

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is not an identity. You missed "$= e$"

Comment: my bad. was in a hurry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x)^{\cot x} & =\lim_{x \to 0} ((1+(\cos x-1))^{\frac{1}{\cos x -1}})^{(\cos x -1)\cot x}\\\\
& =\lim_{x \to 0} e^{(\cos x -1)\cot x}\\\\
& =e^{{\lim_{x \to 0} {(\cos x -1)\cot x}}}\\\\&
=e^0\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you kind sire

Comment: @SamarthSaluja you're welcome.

Comment: You can't apply a limit to just part of an expression. Specifically in this case, from $\lim f(x) = e$ you can't conclude $\lim f(x)^{g(x)} = \lim e^{g(x)}$.

Comment: The function $F(u,v)=u^v$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^+\!\times\Bbb R$, so if $u\to e$ and $v\to0$, then $u^v\to e^0=1$. Consequently, $\;\lim [f(x)^{g(x)}]=[\lim f(x)]^{\lim g(x)}.$

Comment: @bb_823, good answer (+1).